# Meteor iron:router routecontroller change context of this

Tags: meteor, routes, this, iron-router

I have a function that checks if the user is logged in and it looks like this:

```
var requireLogin = function () {
    if (! Meteor.user()) {
        if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
            this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
        } else {
            this.render('accessDenied');
        }
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
};
```

It is a simple function and it works when i use it on a hook like this:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: 'postSubmit'});
```

However, when i try to call it in an extended routecontroller like this:

```
LogInController = RouteController.extend({
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        requireLogin();
    }
});
```

It does not work. However i can just paste the context of the function into onBeforeAction in the logincontroller and it will work.

```
LogInController = RouteController.extend({
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        if (! Meteor.user()) {
            if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
                this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
            } else {
                this.render('accessDenied');
            }
        } else {
            this.next();
        }
    }
});
```

so what do i need to do? Do i need to pass the value of this into the requireLogin function or is there a smarter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can solve this problem by using javascript's `bind` function, which binds the function to the context:

```
LogInController = RouteController.extend({
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        requireLogin.bind(this)();
    }
});
```

However, that might not even be necessary, if you just pass the function as value directly, thereby avoiding the redirection that may cause the change in context:

```
LogInController = RouteController.extend({
    onBeforeAction: requireLogin
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Christian. I already tried passing the function directly, but i got a syntax error. I did not know about the bind function. Thank you very much.